# Hash Table with 64 bit values as key

Tags: c, hash

I have a hash table whose keys are 64 bit values. The Table size can be of different lengths of power 2, such as 2, 4, 8 etc... I want a hash table function that works well for such cases, that is, it has minimum collisions. As an example, If I want a table size of 32, the hash function should produce values from 0 to 31 with minimum collision for 64 bit inputs.

I have found good solutions for 32 bit inputs but none for 64 bits inputs yet.

For 32 bit keys, I'm using this function

```
#define hash32(x)   ( (x) * 2654435761 )

unsigned int getHashKey( unsigned long x )
{
  return hash32(x) >> ( 32 - h_bits );
}
```

Would to be interesting to have the hash32(x) equivalent of 64 bit.

Comment: What exactly don't you like in how it works?

Comment: @sharptooth: It has too much collisions.

Comment: I hope that "6" was a typo (6 is a multiple of 2, not a power of 2).

Comment: Have you tried elfhash()? It's been used in UNIX and has been proven to be good for what it does.  http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3114/Summer11/Notes/T16.HashFunctions.pdf All you have to do is mod the result to whatever table size (32, 64, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working pretty fine. It uses the FVN hash constant for 64 bit, http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/.

```
#define hash64(x)       ( (unsigned long)(x) * 14695981039346656037 )
#define H_BITS          4   // Hashtable size = 2 ^ 4 = 16
#define H_SHIFT_64      ( 64 - H_BITS )

unsigned int getHashKey( unsigned long x )
{
  return hash64(x) >> H_SHIFT_64;
}
```

Comment: You did FVN wrong way. FVN has mul with  FNV_prime, not with offset_basis

Answer (score 1):

The search for a perfect hash function is like the search for the Holy Grail. Anyway it depends on the value.

If you need a general-purpose hashing functions on x86, Murmur2, Meiyan, SBox, and CRC32 provide good performance for all kinds of keys. For 64bit values you can also try CityHash .

Comment: Is there any thing simple available, like the equivalent of hash32(x) (I have defined above in my post) macro for 64 bits?

Comment: int64 CityHash64(const char *s, size_t len). You can write a macro over this and it;s the same.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cris.com/~Ttwang/tech/inthash.htm) page (and [this](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html)) has a few hash functions suitable for integers. Here's one for 64 bit integers:

```
public long hash64shift(long key)
{
  key = (~key) + (key << 21); // key = (key << 21) - key - 1;
  key = key ^ (key >>> 24);
  key = (key + (key << 3)) + (key << 8); // key * 265
  key = key ^ (key >>> 14);
  key = (key + (key << 2)) + (key << 4); // key * 21
  key = key ^ (key >>> 28);
  key = key + (key << 31);
  return key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 32-bit hash is a multiplicative hash using a prime near to the golden ratio as suggested by Knuth in TAOCP.

```
phi = 0.5 * (sqrt(5) - 1) = 0.618...

2^32 * phi = 2654435769.497...

2^64 * phi = 11400714819323198485.951...
```

2654435761 is the nearest prime in the 32-bit case. With 64 bits, it's 11400714819323198549. So the algorithm becomes:

```
unsigned int getHashKey(unsigned long x) {
    return (x * 11400714819323198549ul) >> (64 - h_bits);
}
```